# Errors During Extension and Version Upgrades

Tags: wordpress, upgrade, extension

WordPress v6.4.2 CiviCRM v5.68.0

This is the error like clockwork. Usually, it reads "502 Server Error" on the webpage and then about 30 seconds later or so, everything works.

```
An error of type E_ERROR was caused in line 338 of the file /home/xxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Page/Extensions.php. Error message: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to CRM_Admin_Page_Extensions::createExtendedInfo() must be an instance of CRM_Extension_Info, null given, called in /home/xxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Form/Extensions.php on line 77 and defined in /home/xxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Page/Extensions.php:338
Stack trace:
#0 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Form/Extensions.php(77): CRM_Admin_Page_Extensions::createExtendedInfo(NULL)
#1 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(717): CRM_Admin_Form_Extensions->preProcess()
#2 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Display.php(76): CRM_Core_Form->buildForm()
#3 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Display->perform(Object(CRM_Admin_Form_Extensions), 'display')
#4 /home/xxxxxx/public_htm
```